# Django Haystack: How to index field from another class

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a django model `Story` which I am successfully able to index using templates. However there is another model `Reviews` which has a static method which takes `Story` object and returns `ratings` as Integer. How can I index `Story` on `ratings` also.

```
{{ object.story_name }}
{{Reviews.ratings(object)}}
```

I tried to call this method in template `story_text.txt`, but that results in an error.

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '(object)'....
```

**Edit:**
I tried using below in template, it doesn't give any error while building the index. But how can I now refer to this field while searching using `SearchQuerySet`

```
Reviews.average_start_rating( {{object}} )
```

Comment: Try `{{ Reviews.ratings object }}` or `args=(object,)`

Comment: Not working, failing with same error, `Could not parse the remainder`

Comment: Can you show your `ratings` code?

Comment: I would suggest for you to try out Django Context Processors.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. I don't think that you can use syntax like {{ Reviews.rating object }} with template engine in Django. If it is possible, that is what I didn't know.

Why don't you pass what you want to show in template in Context in the first place?

{{ object }} could be rendered because it has object in Context. For example, if you use UpdateView(class based view), It contains object in Context automatically.

```
class Example(UpdateView):
    model = yourClass
    form_class = yourFormClass
    template_name = yourhtml
    success_url = URL redirect page after success
```

you can use `{{object}}` in yourhtml.html because of UpdateView. you give pk number in url conf like `(?P<pk>[0-9]+)`.

you can do like this without UpdateView

```
class anotherExample(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        render(request, 'yourhtml.html', {"object": Class.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])})
```

in form view, you can use

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['object'] = Class.objects.get(id= ... )
    return context
```

my idea is passing story object and review object which has FK of story object together in context.

Comment: The template I am using in haystack template, I found out a way to add the field for indexing. Will add answer eventually. Doing some research.

Comment: I see. then, I totally misunderstood your question. I will check django haystack and your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using haystack advanced-data-preparation.
[Advanced Data Preparation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation)

Using an additional field one can have a prepare method for that. However only issue is I can order the data using this field but can't search using it.

```
class StoryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    ratings = indexes.FloatField()

    def prepare_ratings(self, obj):
        return Reviews.ratings(obj)

    def get_model(self):
        return Story
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a template for the `text` field, here you can use the [prepare](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchindex_api.html#prepare-self-object) or [prepare_FOO](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchindex_api.html#prepare-foo-self-object) methods:

```
class StoryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    # text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    # ratings = indexes.FloatField()

    def prepare_text(self, obj):
        return "\n".join(f"{col}" for col in [obj.story_name, Reviews.ratings(obj)])

    def get_model(self):
        return Story
```